# Intellij Idea - Apply javascript code completion on .blade.php view files across project

Tags: intellij-idea, code-completion

I'm having a little issue. I have some javascript in my blade view files. Let's say I declare a function or set a variable. When I refer to the variable, Intellij IDEA not recognizing it and not offering code completion.

When I add a regular .html file to the project - the IDE instantly recognizes it across other files in the project.

How can I achieve this behavior using blade files ?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Please vote for [WEB-41572](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-41572) to be notified on any progress with it

Comment: Hi Lena. Thanks. Is there any workaround until an official fix?

Comment: No, nothing I'm aware of